# How to disable all control over WPF WebBrowser control but not the HTML page it displays

Tags: c#, wpf, google-maps-api-3, webbrowser-control

I am working on a project to bring the Google Maps JavaScript API V3 to WPF by displaying a HTML page containing the map control and all JavaScript functions in a WebBrowser control in WPF. I then use InvokeScript on the WebBrowser to run the JavaScript functions I wrote so I can essentially control the map from C# using the JavaScript as a bridge between the two.

This is not a problem as such but a requirement. I do not want the user to have any control of the WebBrowser at all except the map on the page. So how can I eliminate all controls on it? Everything from every ContextMenu on the page and any text to the F5 refresh shortcut to the popups that appear asking to enable features or ActiveX needs to be removed or at least surpressed so they don't do anything and I end up with a control that just renders its HTML source with the user having no control over anything but what is on the page (the map). How can I do this if it is possible, thanks.

Comment: Try busy indicator in Extended WPF Toolkit
http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator

Comment: @MayurDhingra That looks like it is a notification, I want to disable all control on a WebBrowser so it only renders the page which the user can interact with.

Answer (score 0):

@HenryHunt, Do you mean disable Context menu (right click option)? Then set the        `IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled' to  'False` in the Properties window.

Comment: Also you can choose which options you want to disable like "Navigtion","Shortcuts" and etc by properties window

Comment: I'm using WPF so this isn't a property. I also need to remove the F5 refresh action and anything else so all I get is a control that renders the page but does not allow the user to interact with the browser part of it (they should be able to interact with the page though)

Answer (score 0):

```
using mshtml;

private mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event documentEvents;
```

in constructor or xaml set your LoadComplete event:

```
webBrowser.LoadCompleted += webBrowser_LoadCompleted;
```

then in that method create your new webbrowser document object and view the available properties and create new events as follows:

```
private void webBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    documentEvents = (HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event)webBrowserChat.Document; // this will access the events properties as needed
    documentEvents.oncontextmenu += webBrowserChat_ContextMenuOpening;
}

private bool webBrowserChat_ContextMenuOpening(IHTMLEventObj pEvtObj)
{
    return false; // ContextMenu wont open
    // return true;  ContextMenu will open
    // Here you can create your custom contextmenu or whatever you want
}
```